# Removing Tag/Scoreboard Value from Offline Players

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

For my Minecraft: Bedrock Edition Realm, I am creating a system where players can purchase access to a certain area for 24 hours. So far, I have created the purchasing system and 24-hour timer. When a player purchases access, they are given a tag so that they and only they can enter the area during the time period. After the time is up, the tag must be removed so someone else can purchase access. The problem arises if they are offline when the time is up. I currently have no way to remove the tag from them if they are offline, and waiting until they come online again means the whole system is stuck until they come back (if they do) meaning no one else can purchase access until they come back. I want a solution that will allow a reset of the system when the time ends, allowing someone else to rent soon after. I am open to using scoreboard objectives instead of tags if that seems like a better option.

Comment: Did you try messing with your commands a bit...?

Comment: Yes, but not for that long. Should I try more? I'm having trouble thinking of any solutions. I read a little about linking a player with an armor stand via scoreboard values, but couldn't find any in-depth explanations.

Comment: Maybe, or share this question to productive media. Your chances of getting a reputable answer is increased there.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, have you tried the /tickingarea command? This creates an area that is always loaded, so things like command blocks and redstone systems should still work in the area, even if the chunks are not loaded by a player being there. I'm not sure if it would work if they're all offline, as I'm not very familiar with how realms work, but I would recommend you give it a try. There's more info here on the Minecraft wiki: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Ticking_area

Comment: Also, out of interest, could you tell me a bit more about your payment system? Is it a manual thing you manage, or is there some kind of web interface which links to the realm?

Comment: Using a ticking area won't work because command blocks can't target offline players, with or without a ticking area. The payment system is just a /clear system where players pay with diamonds. (Not real money)

Comment: Oh ok, do you know if ticking areas work even when all the players offline? I think linking players with armour stands is probably your best bet, unless command blocks can target offline players with a scoreboard selector? Also, is your restricted area set up such that it is suited only to the presence of one player at a time? Or could you make it so that one player could purchase access when another still had access?

Comment: I did some testing, and ticking areas apear to work offline. There are 3 different areas that can be rented, and I want only one person to be able to access them at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, it will be impossible for a proper timer as the Realm will shut down when nobody is on it, as well as Realms worlds shutting down for periodic maintenance at times.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks for the help anyway!